# How to hide/show element via JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the the table "trackdata" and hide "notrackdata" table whenever I click the button. As of now the table "notrackdata" hides but "trackdata" doesn't show.

**HTML**

```
<button class="far fa-file-audio fa-3x" id = "audiotrack" onclick = "searchtrack()"></button>

<table style = "width:90%" class = "notrackdata" id = "notrackdata"> //NOTRACKDATA 
    <tr>
        <th>NO TRACK DATA TO SHOW<br><img class = "fas fa-sad-tear fa-2x" id ="tear"></th>
    </tr>
</table>

<table style = "width:90%" class = "trackdata" id ="trackdata"> //TRACKDATA
    <th >
        <tr class = "trackrow">
            <td>Album Cover</td>
            <td>Album Title</td>
            <td>Artist</td>
            <td>Track Preview</td>
        </tr>
    </th>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img src ="https:\/\/e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net\/images\/artist\/72f073a5829b368025b49c460b4b1918\/250x250-000000-80-0-0.jpg" id = "imageBox"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
function searchtrack(){
   var input = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
   document.getElementById("trackdata").style.display = "display"; //Display trackdata
   document.getElementById("notrackdata").style.display = "none"; //Hide notrackdata
}
```

**CSS**

```
.trackdata{
   background-color: #DCDCDC;
   margin:auto;
   margin-top:1%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

If I use display ="block"; and display = "inline-block I lose the CSS stylings. How can I make sure to keep the stylings while displaying the table as block or inline-block?

Comment: use this `document.getElementById("trackdata").style.display = "block";` instead of doing this stuff `document.getElementById("trackdata").style.display = "display";`

Comment: There is no HTML element with id = userinput. That is why it was not working.

Answer (score 3):

The value `display` is not supported for the property `display`. When you want to show the element, you should use the value `block` instead.

You can read more about the accepted values [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

```js
function searchtrack(){
   var input = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
   document.getElementById("trackdata").style.display = "block"; //Display trackdata
   document.getElementById("notrackdata").style.display = "none"; //Hide notrackdata
}
```

Comment: Whenever I used display = "block" or display = "inline-block" it doesn't show the other styling e.g. text-align:center;

Comment: Can you update your question including the expected style you wants to display? From the original question I could not find this problem you mentioned

Comment: Ok, i edited the stylings I want to have in the table...and also explained what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a `class` and add it to `trackdata`. On click add this class to `notrackdata` and remove from `trackdata`

```js
function searchtrack() {
  //var input = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
  document.getElementById("trackdata").classList.remove('hide')
  document.getElementById("notrackdata").classList.add('hide')
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<button class="far fa-file-audio fa-3x" id="audiotrack" onclick="searchtrack()">Hide</button>

<table style="width:90%" class="notrackdata" id="notrackdata"> //NOTRACKDATA
  <tr>
    <th>NO TRACK DATA TO SHOW<br><img class="fas fa-sad-tear fa-2x" id="tear"></th>
  </tr>
</table>

<table style="width:90%" class="trackdata" id="trackdata"> //TRACKDATA
  <th>
    <tr class="trackrow hide">
      <td>Album Cover</td>
      <td>Album Title</td>
      <td>Artist</td>
      <td>Track Preview</td>
    </tr>
  </th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https:\/\/e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net\/images\/artist\/72f073a5829b368025b49c460b4b1918\/250x250-000000-80-0-0.jpg" id="imageBox"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
JS
```

Answer (score 0):

display = “block” not “display” for including the element in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The `display` attribute takes 'block', 'inline', 'inline-block', or 'none' as values. If you change `display="display"` to `display="block"` you will see your element.

Answer (score 0):

Display property should be set to "block" and not "display".

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to show and hide the table: (click the button to toggle)

```html
<button class="far fa-file-audio fa-3x" id = "audiotrack" onclick="myFunction()">Show/hide</button>
<div id="myDIV">
<table style = "width:90%" class = "notrackdata" id = "notrackdata"> //NOTRACKDATA 
    <tr>
        <th>NO TRACK DATA TO SHOW<br><img class = "fas fa-sad-tear fa-2x" id ="tear"></th>
    </tr>
</table><br>

<table style = "width:90%" class = "trackdata" id ="trackdata"> //TRACKDATA
    <th >
        <tr class = "trackrow">
            <td>Album Cover</td>
            <td>Album Title</td>
            <td>Artist</td>
            <td>Track Preview</td>
        </tr>
    </th>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img src ="https:\/\/e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net\/images\/artist\/72f073a5829b368025b49c460b4b1918\/250x250-000000-80-0-0.jpg" id = "imageBox"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<style>
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;

  text-align: center;

  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
<script>
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
<style>
.hide {
  display: none;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
</style>
```

Comment: When you click the button, it will display it as a block. If you click it again, it will hide it...

Comment: You can keep clicking on the button too

Comment: if you want to make the top row shown always, move the part where it says: <div id="myDIV"> to the desired part, like:

<div id="myDIV">
<table style = "width:90%" class = "trackdata" id ="trackdata"> //TRACKDATA

and so on...

Comment: If you want a tutorial on it, go to: 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 0):

Display property is used to hide/show elements.You have used "display" as a property value.Use "block" instead of "display"

Change it to this

```
document.getElementById("trackdata").style.display = "block";
```

So final Js code will be like this:-

```
function searchtrack()
{
   var input = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
   document.getElementById("trackdata").style.display = "block"; //Display trackdata
   document.getElementById("notrackdata").style.display = "none"; //Hide notrackdata
}
```

For more info - [Hide/show element](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp)